# How do I list all Amazon RDS DB Instance Classes for DB engine oracle-ee using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am trying to list all DB instance class in a format something like this:

`db.t1.micro db.m1.small db.m1.medium db.m1.large db.m1.xlarge db.m2.xlarge db.m2.2xlarge db.m2.4xlarge db.m3.medium db.m3.large db.m3.xlarge db.m3.2xlarge db.m4.large db.m4.xlarge db.m4.2xlarge db.m4.4xlarge db.m4.10xlarge db.r3.large db.r3.xlarge db.r3.2xlarge db.r3.4xlarge db.r3.8xlarge db.t2.micro  db.t2.small db.t2.medium db.t2.large`.

There is a command that list all of the db instance types but I can find a way to `--query` it.

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options  --engine oracle-ee --engine-version 12.1.0.2.v8 --license-model bring-your-own-license --output table
```

Output of this command is huge and I can't help to sort this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options  --engine oracle-ee --engine-version 12.1.0.2.v8 --license-model bring-your-own-license --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text
```

Outputs:

```
db.m1.large db.m1.large db.m1.large db.m1.medium    db.m1.medium
db.m1.medium    db.m1.small db.m1.small db.m1.small db.m1.xlarge
db.m1.xlarge    db.m1.xlarge    db.m2.2xlarge   db.m2.2xlarge
db.m2.2xlarge   db.m2.4xlarge   db.m2.4xlarge   db.m2.4xlarge   
etc
```

However, there are duplicates due to multiple licensing options. A de-duplicated version would be:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options  --engine oracle-ee --engine-version 12.1.0.2.v8 --license-model bring-your-own-license --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text | sed -e 'y/\t/\n/' | uniq
```

Outputs:

```
db.m1.large
db.m1.medium
db.m1.small
db.m1.xlarge
db.m2.2xlarge
db.m2.4xlarge
etc
```

Comment: Thanks John, that fixed it.

Comment: I added a "sort" before the "uniq" to help de-duplicate.

`aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options  --engine oracle-ee --engine-version 12.1.0.2.v8 --license-model bring-your-own-license --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text | sed -e 'y/\t/\n/' | sort | uniq`

Comment: `sort -u` replaces `sort | unique` in one subprocess.